# No graphics in subfigures

Tags: subfloats

So, I have been trying to add three images in a single line.
When I use only the 'figure' function like this

```
    \begin{figure}[t]
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./Figures/img1}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./Figures/img2}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./Figures/img3}
    \end{figure}
```

I get the result that I want.
But once I try using 'subfigure' function like this

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./Figures/img1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./Figures/img2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{./Figures/img3}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

I just get three empty boxes in a row and with 'relax.png' writtten inside them. Moreover, I get a load of errors as well which weren' there when I only used figures.

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage{subfigure}`, or `\usepackage{subcaption}`? (You should have the latter.)

Comment: If you have both you will get errors when you generate the document, and you should never ignore errors. Remove `\usepackage{subfigure}`, it is deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use both packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

will throw the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@subfigure already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.113 \newcounter{subfigure}
                            [figure]
```

while

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

throws

```
! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
(subcaption)                with the subfigure package.

See the subcaption package documentation for explanation.
```

The `subfigure` package is considered deprecated, so I'd recommend `subcaption`. They differ in use however:

- `\usepackage{subfigure}`: defines a `\subfigure` macro, used as `\subfigure[<subcaption>]{<figure>}`
- `\usepackage{subcaption}`: defines an environment, used as

  ```
  \begin{subfigure}{<width>}
  <figure>
  \caption{<caption>}
  \end{subfigure}
  ```

  Note that you have to specify a width for the environment, similar to `minipage`. Hence, a working version of your code snippet would be

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Figures/img1}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Figures/img2}
  \end{subfigure}\hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./Figures/img3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \end{figure}
  \end{document}
  ```

Answer (score 1):

With the `subfigure` package the official use is

```
\subfigure{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{image}}
```

not an environment.

You can use the environment if you put `{}` around the `\includegraphics`:

```
\begin{subfigure}
{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{image}}
\end{subfigure}
```